# My sol stuck in prgram. How can I close program and recover it?

Tags: solana-program, program, getprogramaccounts, deploy

I was deploying program and by mistake I **missed the keyword program** and just typed

```
solana deploy <PROGRAM_FILEPATH>
```

which return the below program Id and there is no upgradeable authority. Now I want to close this program and recover my sol.

> 4NSU1oLcDRaDEitdHXNky8DZbqweogyYmZ3gwBPgMv6k

Is there any solution regarding can I recover my sol from this program and close it.
Thank you!

Comment: did you run solana program close <yourprogramaccountaddress>

Comment: yes I tried but it gives me this error

`Error: 4NSU1oLcDRaDEitdHXNky8DZbqweogyYmZ3gwBPgMv6k is not a Program or Buffer account`

Comment: make sure you are on the correct cluster

Comment: Thanks for reply how can I confirm this?
If i am on right cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the`solana deploy` command deploys immutable program. They should probably let you know beforehand.

Comment: By default, the program deployed is not immutable. One must use `--final` to make a program immutable.

Comment: OK Thanks mate. 
So I just lost sol.

Comment: For the comment about not immutable programs, see [this](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/27264#event-7224083134) issue, basically the loader was updated and the old loader `solana deploy` shouldn't be used in favor of the new loader `solana program deploy`.

Answer (score -1):

You can close the program using the following command and recover the SOL

`solana program close <PROGRAM_ADDRESS>`